# A property of Infinite sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove the following:

If $X$ is an infinite set, then for every $f:X \rightarrow X,$ there exists a nonempty subset of $X$, which is denoted as $A$, such that $A \ne X$, and $f(A) \subset A$.

I am thinking about using the property that every infinite set is equivalent to a proper subset, but fail to make a breakthrough.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Think about what happens if you start by putting one element in $A$.  What other elements then have to be in $A$?

Comment: Hint: pick $a_1\in X$ arbitrarily. If $f(a_1)=a_1$ then you're done. If not, let $a_2=f(a_1)$. If $f(a_2)=a_1$ then you're done (why?); if not, let $a_3=f(a_2)$.... At the end one might choose to leave $a_1$ out of $A$.

Comment: Oh great, let me think about this. Thank you Greg and Eric!

Comment: This requires some form of the Axiom of Choice, right?

Comment: @RobertShore it doesn't. Standard method: choose some $a \in X$ and consider all functions of form $\{1, \ldots, n\} \to X$ s.t. $g(1) = a$ and $g(n + 1) = f(g(n))$, then take their union.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT(1): use the following theorem. EDIT(1): Based on the comments, it may be worth mentioning that the Axiom of Choice is not needed to prove the theorem.

**Theorem**. Let $X$ be a set. Fix $f:X\to X$. Fix $a\in X$. There exists a unique function $f^{(\cdot)}(a):\mathbb{N}\to X$ such that $$f^{0}(a)=a\qquad\text{and}\qquad f^{n+1}(a)=f(f^{n}(a))$$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

HINT(2): If there exists $n'\ne 0$ such that $f^{n'}(a)=a$, then $\{f^{n}(a):n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a finite set.

HINT(3): If for each $n'\ne 0$, $f^{n'}(a)\ne a$, then $\{f^{n}(a):n\in\mathbb{N}\}\setminus\{a\}\subsetneq X$.